# Making a Quilt of square using JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, for-loop, javafx, nested

I have been trying to build a Quilt using JavaFX using nested for loops. I have been trying this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        square=new Rectangle(50,50);
        square.setFill(squareColor);           
        square.setX(x);

        root.getChildren().add(square);
        x=x+100;

        for(int j=0;j<=5;j++)
        {
            square=new Rectangle(50,50);
            square.setFill(squareColor);
            square.setY(y);               
            y=y+100;                               
            root.getChildren().add(square);


        }
```

I don't get it...I always need to declare a new Rectangle object in each loop. Is there a possible way to use the same rectangle called "square" here in both for loops.

Comment: It's not clear why you're creating a `Rectangle` in the outer loop.

Answer (score 4):

Why not do

```
for (int x = 0 ; x <= 500 ; x+= 100) {
    for (int y = 0 ; y <= 500 ; y+= 100) {
        Rectangle square = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);
        root.getChildren().add(square);
    }
}
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Quilt extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Paint squareColor = Color.AQUAMARINE ;

        for (int x = 0 ; x <= 500 ; x+=100) {
            for (int y = 0 ; y <= 500 ; y+=100) {
                Rectangle square = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);
                square.setFill(squareColor);
                root.getChildren().add(square);
            }
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]